# ListBox Columns with Collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an application that randomizes a list of teams and then display the matchups.
As you can see from the picture everything works except the matchups are suppose to be on the same row. I do know the cause of this but I'm not sure how to properly fix it(If possible). Also, I apologize for the title - I didn't know what to call it.

[image: Application Example]

I believe the cause is when I'm adding to the MatchUp ObservableCollection I am not putting both Team1 and Team2 into the Add function, which means it's left blank?

```
void GetRandomMatchUps()
        {
            randomNums.Clear();
            MatchUp.Clear();

            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            int randomPick;
            bool completed = false;
            int count = 0;
            while(!completed)
            {
                randomPick = random.Next(0, team.Count);
                if (!randomNums.Contains(randomPick))
                {
                    randomNums.Add(randomPick);
                    count++;
                    if(count % 2 == 0)
                        MatchUp.Add(new Round() { Team1 = team[randomPick].Name });

                    else
                        MatchUp.Add(new Round() { Team2 = team[randomPick].Name });
                }
                else if(randomNums.Count == team.Count)
                {
                    completed = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

XAML

```
<ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Height="200" Name="matchList">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Team1}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="VS" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Team2}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

CLASS

```
class Round
    {
        public string Team1 { get; set; }
        public string Team2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You never create a Round where you set Team1 and Team2 at the same time.

Comment: @Clemens I realise that, but my problem is if I put them together where I have it now, team1 and team2 will have the same value. So how can I set the values without creating a new round each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple method creates a collection of random matches:

```
public static IEnumerable<Round> CreateRandomMatches(List<Team> teams)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var randomTeams = teams.OrderBy(t => random.Next()).ToList();

    for (int i = 1; i < teams.Count; i += 2)
    {
        yield return new Round
        {
            Team1 = randomTeams[i - 1].Name,
            Team2 = randomTeams[i].Name
        };
    }
}
```